# How to make HTTPS Post request to .NET server from Android?

Tags: java, android, json, post, https

I am working on the Android app, and a friend is working on the much more complex .NET server code for a service. I have been informed that now, the JSON data that I send to him by POST and the much larger JSON data that I receive from him must be over HTTPS. All of the tutorials I have found are either just for standard HTTP or require writing several classes just to handle the secure connection. I am new to Android development so that would not be ideal. I'm not even sure that my current code would pull down the data from the server WITHOUT a secure connection.

Where do I start? What changes do I need to make?

I would be happy to provide additional information as needed, I've been obsessing over this code for over a week. When requesting information, please be as descriptive as possible.

HttpClient.java

```
public class HttpClient {

public static final String TAG = HttpClient.class.getSimpleName();

public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.v("After converting Stream to String", resultString);
            instream.close();

            // Transform the String into a JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);

            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;

        } 

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // More about HTTP exception handling in another tutorial.
        // For now we just print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     * 
     * (c) public domain: http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

LogCat Errors, starting on a button click that initializes some JSON data (which has been made correctly) and then uses HttpClient.java:

```
08-29 12:47:16.697: W/ActivityThread(9547): Application com.barjinx.barjinx can be debugged on port 8100...
08-29 12:47:17.033: D/libEGL(9547): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-29 12:47:17.057: D/libEGL(9547): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-29 12:47:17.072: D/libEGL(9547): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-29 12:47:17.236: D/OpenGLRenderer(9547): Enabling debug mode 0
08-29 12:47:27.486: D/dalvikvm(9547): GC_CONCURRENT freed 92K, 2% free 9133K/9256K, paused 16ms+9ms, total 50ms
08-29 12:47:27.525: V/EventsActivity(9547): JSON Created: {"search":{"GeoLat":"29.7529","GeoZip":"78757","SearchTerm":"Rangers","GeoLong":"-97.7333","UserKey":"MattCoker"}}
08-29 12:47:36.361: I/HttpClient(9547): HTTPResponse received in [8826ms]
08-29 12:47:36.369: W/System.err(9547): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-29 12:47:36.393: D/dalvikvm(9547): GC_CONCURRENT freed 230K, 3% free 9316K/9576K, paused 3ms+9ms, total 32ms
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at com.barjinx.barjinx.HttpClient.SendHttpPost(HttpClient.java:53)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at com.barjinx.barjinx.EventsActivity$GetEventsDataTask.sendUserJSON(EventsActivity.java:172)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at com.barjinx.barjinx.EventsActivity$GetEventsDataTask.doInBackground(EventsActivity.java:142)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at com.barjinx.barjinx.EventsActivity$GetEventsDataTask.doInBackground(EventsActivity.java:1)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-29 12:47:36.408: W/System.err(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-29 12:47:36.416: W/System.err(9547):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-29 12:47:36.416: W/System.err(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-29 12:47:36.416: W/System.err(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-29 12:47:36.416: W/System.err(9547):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-29 12:47:36.416: W/dalvikvm(9547): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e13930)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at com.barjinx.barjinx.EventsActivity$GetEventsDataTask.sendUserJSON(EventsActivity.java:173)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at com.barjinx.barjinx.EventsActivity$GetEventsDataTask.doInBackground(EventsActivity.java:142)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at com.barjinx.barjinx.EventsActivity$GetEventsDataTask.doInBackground(EventsActivity.java:1)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-29 12:47:36.424: E/AndroidRuntime(9547):     ... 4 more
08-29 12:48:08.900: I/Process(9547): Sending signal. PID: 9547 SIG: 9
08-29 12:48:45.353: W/ActivityThread(9753): Application com.barjinx.barjinx is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
08-29 12:48:45.361: I/System.out(9753): Sending WAIT chunk
08-29 12:48:45.486: I/dalvikvm(9753): Debugger is active
08-29 12:48:45.564: I/System.out(9753): Debugger has connected
08-29 12:48:45.564: I/System.out(9753): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-29 12:48:45.768: I/System.out(9753): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-29 12:48:45.971: I/System.out(9753): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-29 12:48:46.166: I/System.out(9753): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-29 12:48:46.369: I/System.out(9753): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-29 12:48:46.572: I/System.out(9753): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-29 12:48:46.768: I/System.out(9753): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-29 12:48:46.971: I/System.out(9753): debugger has settled (1326)
08-29 12:48:47.510: D/libEGL(9753): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-29 12:48:47.510: D/libEGL(9753): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-29 12:48:47.518: D/libEGL(9753): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
08-29 12:48:47.588: D/OpenGLRenderer(9753): Enabling debug mode 0
08-29 12:49:09.189: D/dalvikvm(9753): GC_CONCURRENT freed 80K, 2% free 9131K/9240K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 24ms
08-29 12:49:09.275: V/EventsActivity(9753): JSON Created: {"search":{"GeoLat":"29.7529","GeoZip":"78757","SearchTerm":"Rangers","GeoLong":"-97.7333","UserKey":"MattCoker"}}
```

Comment: Is `response.getEntity();` returning null in your test calls? What is the value of `response.getEntity().getContentLength()` call?

Comment: Well, I think it has a "value" but when I dig down into the content section, it has a content length of 0. And the contentType is null.

Comment: And what is the value of `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()` ?

Comment: Aha, a 404 error. So now what?

Comment: Make sure that you have valid SSL certificate installed on server (with root trusted by Android OS).

Comment: I haven't gotten confirmation of the "root trusted by Android OS" but I have verified it has a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36499/discussion-between-mattcoker-and-user2714032)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that SSL certificate is installed properly on server. You can use http://www.digicert.com/help/ tool for that.

If you use self signed certificate then you have to follow:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html